# Completely removing phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, suexec

I installed virtualmin and phpmyadmin separately using the apt-get command. phpMyAdmin didn't work because of Virtualmin's security settings (suexec).
When I visit mydomain.com/phpmyadmin, it would download the whole PHP page instead of execute it.
I tried disabling suexec but it didn't work.
So now I want to remove phpMyAdmin.
I removed it using the apt-get remove command and also deleted the /etc/phpmyadmin folder.
But still, when I visit mydomain.com/phpmyadmin, it downloads the page. It probably means phpmyadmin wasn't completely deleted.

What is the problem?

Please help.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If your system is using dpkg and apt (debian, ubuntu, etc), try running the following commands in that order (be careful with the `sudo rm` commands):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin  
sudo rm -vf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo rm -vfR /usr/share/phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Sometimes dpkg wont purge phpmyadmin files, so you can run:
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Comment: some time you also need to run -> sudo apt-get -f install before all above commands.
If you receive error like this ->Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 56):

I had to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin
```

Then I cleared my cache and it worked!

Comment: This worked great for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: it does not work for Mac osx:(

Comment: Sometimes (linux) you may also delete phpmyadmin's folder:
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar problem. PHP was working on my sites configured by virtualmin but not for phpmyadmin. PHPMyAdmin would not execute and the file was being downloaded by the browser.  Everything I was reading was saying that libapache2-mod-php5 was not installed but I knew it was... so the thing to do was to purge it and reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `purge`

```
sudo aptitude purge phpmyadmin
```

Not sure this works with plain old `apt-get` though

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Try the following command. This solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```