# Remove privileges from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, privileges, sql-grant

Before you think this is a duplicate question, I believe I have a unique, even if it is somewhat dim-witted, case.

A few days ago, I upgraded the version of MySQL on my Ubuntu 10.04 server to 5.3.3 (it's ahead of the Ubuntu releases for 10.04). Today, I attempted to log into phpMyAdmin for something and discovered the somewhat dreaded `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed` error.

After following descriptions from several SO questions on how to fix this, I have become stuck.

- I attempted to [reconfigure phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179473/379636), with no success.
- I attempted to [uninstall phpMyAdmin and reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136038/379636) it, but it couldn't remove the privileges from the DB and failed.
- I then attempted to [manually remove the privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287377/revoke-all-privileges-for-all-users-on-a-mysql-db) of the user - somewhat foolishly, I might add - from the DB, then dropping the db, then the user (with `flush privileges`).
- I dropped the whole install of phpMyAdmin completely (deleting the application and the /etc/phpmyadmin directory) and reinstalled (using apt-get) but it said the permissions for the phpmyadmin user already existed:

`granting access to database phpmyadmin for phpmyadmin@localhost: already exists`

So, here is what I'm left with. I have a grant that I cannot modify, nor revoke:

```
mysql> show grants for 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for phpmyadmin@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*46CFC7938B60837F46B610A2D10C248874555C14' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.26 sec)

mysql> revoke usage on *.* from 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'phpmyadmin' on host 'localhost'

mysql> revoke usage on *.* from 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' identified by 'trustno1';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'phpmyadmin' on host 'localhost'
```

(Don't worry, I do not use this password anymore, but it was the password that was used previously and it is not the password I chose for the new phpmyadmin installation).

How do I totally remove these grants/privileges? I am happy to start again from scratch if need be (phpmyadmin that is, not the DB).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The USAGE-privilege in mysql simply means that there are no privileges for the user 'phpadmin'@'localhost' defined on global level `*.*`. Additionally the same user has ALL-privilege on database phpmyadmin `phpadmin.*`.

So if you want to remove all the privileges and start totally from scratch do the following:

- Revoke all privileges on database level:

  `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpmyadmin.* FROM 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';`
- Drop the user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'

  `DROP USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';`

Above procedure will entirely remove the user from your instance, this means you can recreate him from scratch.

To give you a bit background on what described above: as soon as you create a user the `mysql.user` table will be populated. If you look on a record in it, you will see the user and all privileges set to `'N'`. If you do a `show grants for 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';` you will see, the allready familliar, output above. Simply translated to "no privileges on global level for the user". Now your grant `ALL` to this user on database level, this will be stored in the table `mysql.db`. If you do a `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE db = 'nameofdb';` you will see a `'Y'` on every priv.

Above described shows the scenario you have on your db at the present. So having a user that only has `USAGE` privilege means, that this user can connect, but besides of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` he has no other privileges.

Comment: Do you have to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after this?

Comment: I couldn't look at this until today, and your answer solved the privileges problem, thanks. However, my `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed` error remains but that is a different issue.

Comment: `DROP USER` is all you need to completely remove the user access from mysql.user and mysql.db tables.  `REVOKE` simply toggles the permission flags to 'N' in one or both of those tables for the permissions specified, but leaves user intact.  And yes, you need to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after a `REVOKE` statement, but not after a `DROP` operation.

Comment: Note that you grant "to" a user and revoke "from" a user. I thought the keyword was the same for the revoke command and did not understand why I was getting the syntax error `ERROR 1064 (42000)`.

Comment: @JoeyT the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command was not needed in my case after a `GRANT` or `REVOKE` command and should not be needed for other people either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463966/when-is-flush-privileges-in-mysql-really-needed

Answer (score 17):

As a side note, the reason `revoke usage on *.* from 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';` does not work is quite simple : There is no grant called `USAGE`.

[The actual named grants are in the MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)

The grant `USAGE` is a logical grant. How? 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' has an entry in `mysql.user` where user='phpmyadmin' and host='localhost'. Any row in mysql.user semantically means `USAGE`. Running `DROP USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';` should work just fine. Under the hood, it's really doing this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='phpmyadmin' and host='localhost';
DELETE FROM mysql.db   WHERE user='phpmyadmin' and host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Therefore, the removal of a row from `mysql.user` constitutes running `REVOKE USAGE`, even though `REVOKE USAGE` cannot literally be executed.