# Stop mySQL GRANT ALL, not just erasing

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

Imagine that I run this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

Now in every new DB, the user has full access. 
The question is, imagine that at some point I want that those *.* privileges don't apply to new databases.
Is that possible?

I just thought about erasing user and GRANT privileges to the last db's created but it could be quite hard if there are a lot of them... and I wondered if there was a "REVOKE from now on ..." hidden from google command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it helped me may be you too

```
REVOKE ALL on dbName.* from 'user'@'host';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: that would erase all privileges to all db's.tables. I just want to stop aplaying "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" to new databases.

Comment: You may filter out by providing dbName as per updated answer. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

***try this:***

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM user [, user] ...
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON *.* FROM user [, user] ...
```

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/revoke.html***

Comment: But it would revoke Privileges to all the databases, wound't it? I was thinking about not granting from now on but keeping the old ones

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799806/remove-privileges-from-mysql-database

Comment: thanks but not enough. They show how to erase privileges.. I just want to stop applying to new databases without erasing them for each new db.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this

```
REVOKE [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] FROM ‘[username]’@‘localhost’;
```

- ALL PRIVILEGES- this would allow a MySQL user all access to a designated database (or if no database is selected, across the system)
- CREATE- allows them to create new tables or databases
- DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
- DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables
- INSERT- allows them to insert rows into tables
- SELECT- allows them to use the Select command to read through databases
- UPDATE- allow them to update table rows

***https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql***

Comment: The problem is that ON [database name] doesn't answear the question. I just want that those privileges don't apply to NEW databases. As you show, I would have to run that command to every new database.