# Uninstalled PhpMyAdmin on linux server, now apache restart gives this error

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, lamp, apc

ALREADY SOLVED

I had a LAMP setup and PHPMyAdmin running on linux VPS. Worked great, however I did not need PHPMyAdmin anymore, so I removed it (like this: [Completely removing phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050296/completely-removing-phpmyadmin))

However, now if I restart Apache I get this error:

```
Syntax error on line 244 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration 
file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Does anyone now how to solve this?

I have APC configured and running btw. Might it have something todo with APC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it already. etc/apache2/apache2.conf still had an include for phpmyadmin. Removed that one and everything is working fine again!

Comment: nearly had a heart attack but this saved me quickly. Thank you.